# Where should I store data that can be accessed outside of the view thread?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-intentservice

I'm using IntentServices to call a restful service and then turn over the result to a receiver.  The back-end requires a user id and authentication token, which I stored in a singleton class.  I've run into issues with this singleton being cleaned up when the process is terminated, and its data isn't around when Android tries to restart my activities.  User preferences seem like a great place to start this kind of data, but those require a reference to your context.

Where can I put this data so it can be accessed outside of the view?  I realize I could just pass it with every single Intent that triggers my IntentService, but am hoping there's a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a ContextWrapper which is a Context so you can use the keyword this when getting an instance of your shared prefs.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

For lightweight data such as a few strings etc, SharedPreferences is fine. Just pass any context, every component has one or is one itself. Or pass the application context. Lack of context shouldn't be an issue. Pass it along into your singleton as a parameter.

Using a database, or inventing a proprietary storage mechanism using a file, or creating a content provider, all seem overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass it all the time (which is not that bad), and you still want to stay in the Android framework philosophy, create a ContentProvider for this task.

Or you can go full classical and save them in some file. Or in a sqlite database (Android offers easy support for this).